# ionic 3 - How to add a 'dont ask me again' checkbox to an alert controller?

Tags: typescript, checkbox, alert, ionic3

I'm using ionic3 and want to add a "don't ask me again" checkbox to an alert. As you can see below my alert has three options:

1.save and continue

2.continue without saving

3.cancel

When the user clicks the checkbox only the option "save and continue" should be enabled and the rest disabled.

[image: Here is an example image.]

The thing is I cannot find a way to catch the **checkbox** clicking event in order to do that.
Any ideas?
I build the alert with alert controller, not html.

Comment: "When the user clicks the checkbox only one option should be enabled and the rest disabled" ... What options? The options in the alert, options in the form? Hard to understand this question

Comment: I edited the question. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

the alert controller has an option called `inputs` :

```
 this
  .alert
  .create({
    title: 'Warning',
    inputs: [
      {
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: 'don\'t ask me again',
        handler:(e)=>{
          // e.checked is the checkbox value (true or false)
           console.info('value: ',e.checked)
        }
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'save and continue',
        handler: () => {
          //Do save stuff
        }
      },
       {
        text: 'continue without saving',
        handler: () => {
          //Do continue without saving stuff
        }
      },{text:'cancel'}
    ]
  }).present()
```

Comment: Nice solution. Small issue in that the apostrophe in "don't ask me again" requires escaping. (Too small an edit for me to be permitted to fix it myself on here)